# Call to undefined function in Array

Tags: php

i have a Problem with my PHP Code. I get an "Fatal error: Call to undefined function fabo_autor()" Error on the following Code (Line 2):

```
$message = show(settings('eml_fabo_npost'), array("nick" => re($getabo['nick']),
                                                                    "postuser" => fabo_autor($userid),
                                                                    "topic" => $gettopic['topic'],
                                                                    "titel" => $title,
                                                                    "domain" => $httphost,
                                                                    "id" => intval($_GET['id']),
                                                                    "entrys" => $entrys+1,
                                                                    "page" => $pagenr,
                                                                    "text" => bbcode($_POST['eintrag']),;
```

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Okay, where is that function defined?

Comment: fabo_autor  is implement???

Comment: i think it`s not defined... How can i do this? Should i post a bigger snippet of that code?

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information, kinda hard to help you out there !

Where does `fabo_autor()` function come from ?

Comment: i actually don`t know. The Code is not written by me, i just tried to make some changes. This is the only appereance in the whole PHP File.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry guys, i found my mistake.

I thought it was kind of a syntax error, but my request simply could not be found in my database because of a typo.

Thank you anyways for your reply :)